# Java Servlet - Use one returned object for multiple purposes in view

Tags: java, servlets

Let me clarify my context:

In my index page : I have featured products section, products section and categories which contain products categorized. I use my controller to return a list of products to view. So I think about a solution:

I will pass: 3 different lists of products. So my view is clean with pure EL, no scriplet. But I have to forward a big packets through network which is not efficient.

So are there any other ways to solve this problem ? Thanks first

Answer (score 1):

There's some confusion going on. Those 3 lists are not sent over network. Only the JSP-generated HTML output is been sent over network. Java/JSP/Servlet runs in webserver, not in webbrowser.

If your concrete problem is that those lists are fairly large (e.g, more than 25 rows), then you should consider DB-level pagination. Or, if your concrete problem is that the JSP-generated HTML response is fairly large, then you should consider GZIP compression, it can save up to 80% of network bandwidth. Check the server manual how to enable it. In case of for example Tomcat, it's a matter of adding `compression="on"` to the HTTP `<Connector>` element in `/conf/server.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

One object can have 3 lists as data members.  For example:

```
class IndexViewModel
{
  private List<String> listOne;
  private List<Blam> listTwo;
  private List<Integer> listThree;

  public List<String> getListOne()
  {
    return listOne;
  }

  ... the rest.
}
```

Then in your handler:

```
IndexViewModel indexViewModel;
... fill in the lists
request.addAttribute("BlammyTram", indexViewModel)
```

In your JSP:

```
<c:foreach items="${Blammytram.listOne}">
 ...
</c:foreach>
```